# how to make sure the file created before class import?

Tags: puppet

I am fighting with ensuring things are taking place in the order I specified in puppet :( Here is what I plan to do

```
class A {
  notice("1")
  file{ 'my file':
    force => true,
    replace => 'no',
    ensure  => 'present',
    content => "content",
    owner => 'me',
    group => 'me',
    mode => '0444'
  }
  notice("2")
}

class B {
  require A
  contain target_class_dependent_on_file
}
```

then I call the classes as

```
classA{} -> classB{}
```

and class B always fails because file is not created, 1 and 2 are output just fine before class B. But if I skip classB, I can see file created just fine. I am banging my head against wall now. Can someone please give me some help? many thanks

Comment: btw, I am using puppet 3.8

Answer (score 0):

nvm. This is not a legitimate case. The 'my file' I tried to set up is really to set up a facter. It will never work

Comment: In that case, you should delete your question.  If for some reason you decline to do so, then know that although this would make a suitable comment, it is not an answer.